# Stylinkg Issue on add more option

Tags: html, css

I have a registration form on my website, which forms a basic user employment resume.  To save space on the page some of the form elements have the option to add more fields, now all of these work fine except for the Employment History section.

When you click on the add more button the form appears directly underneath as it should except for the first four fields:

- Job Title
- Company Name
- From
- To

which shift to the left.

I had this issue with all of the add more sections but fixed them as the person who built the page had made some mistakes.  However i can not seem to find the issue, It feels like i have changed everything nut nothing makes a difference.

http://goo.gl/w4WYJm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to add the row class where you generate new elements in your javascript.

```
<div id='jobtitle"+intTextBox+"'>
```

should be

```
<div class="row" id='jobtitle"+intTextBox+"'>
```

You also have a problem which you will find after fixing this, that the descriptionbox has the row class. Fix this by removing it from the job-description and just apply it to the wrapper div as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your website and found the following things.

1) You are trying to show one **div#jobtitle1** on clicking add more. I suggest that please add **class="row"** to that ( this is the class which you people are using for margin )

2) In the same div block which you are showing one more field called Job Description which is again inside a div which has class="row" ( which will again add margin because it is the child div of **div#jobtitle** ) . Please remove that class here.

Try these things then it will be fine.